# Difference between ます and です

Tags: usage, verbs, copula

As a total beginner I noticed that sometimes simple sentences end with ます and sometimes with です. What is the difference?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read much about Japanese grammar yet? You should find an explanation -very- quickly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because one of its paragraphs ends with the word "difference", the other contains only "Thanks" and it's unclear how these two differ.

Comment: i doubt you're going to get an answer. The question is far too basic. 
Start here: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/

Comment: @Thiago ます, ました (past), ません (negative), ませんでした (negative past) are polite verb endings. です is attached to nouns (せんせい teacher), i-adjectives (あかい red) and na-adjectives (きれい(な) clean/neat/beautiful/pretty).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another beginner answering here.

ます is a (polite) verb ending.
The verb to eat (食べる) for example can be conjugated to 食べ*ます*, which can be used in polite speech.

です is a state of being, also to be used in polite conversations and can be roughly translated as a conjugated "to be".
Example: 私はドイツ人*です* (I'm German)

Answer (score 11):

です is the polite form of is/am/are/be. It can also come after adjectives to make a sentence polite. ます is an ending attached to verbs, and functions to make the sentence polite.

> これは猫です。
> This is a cat.
> 今日は暑いです。
> Today is hot.
> ケーキを食べます。
> I eat cake.

Note that in the second example although the translation contains the word **is** this is contained in the adjective 暑い = "be hot". です does not mean **is** when it comes after an adjective, it just makes the sentence polite.

In the third example the verb 食べる (dictionary/plain form) becomes 食べます to make it polite.